# SQL Concatenation using XML Path - multiple rows with multiple table references

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to use the XML Path to run SQL Concatenation but I am running into a bit of a problem. I have one table that is being used as a reference table for values I want to concatenate.I have 3 columns in the reference table (M.PROD, S.PROD, & REF NUMB).

- M.PROD=====>S.PROD======>Ref Numb
- 1===========>**_**===========>981024583
- 2===========>**_**===========>981024719
- 3===========>**A**===========>981024605
- 3===========>**B**===========>981024669
- 4===========>**A**===========>981024688
- 4===========>**B**===========>981024706
- 4===========>**C**===========>981024723
- 5===========>**_**===========>981024742
- 6===========>**_**===========>981024742

I have the main tables where the m.prod and s.prod are used to match the reference table for Ref Numb values. What I want to do is concatenate the Ref Numb values based on what is being selected in main tables. The out put I am looking for is this:

- M.Prod======>Ref Numb
- 1===========>981024583
- 2===========>981024719
- 3===========>981024605, 981024669
- 4===========>981024688, 981024706, 981024723
- 5===========>981024742
- 6===========>981024742

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PRODUCT, 
    (STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + P1.REFNUMB AS [text()]
            FROM PRODUCT P1
            WHERE P1.PRODUCT = P.PRODUCT 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))
FROM PRODUCT P
```

This gives me the output of:

- M.Prod======>Ref Numb
- 1===========>981024583
- 2===========>981024719
- 3===========>981024605, 981024669
- 4===========>981024688, 981024706, 981024723
- 5===========>981024742
- 6===========>981024742

However, there are times where all the s.prod are not in the main tables. So for this I use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PRODUCT, 
    (STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + P1.REFNUMB AS [text()]
            FROM PRODUCT P1
            WHERE P1.PRODUCT = P.PRODUCT AND P1.SUBID = P.SUBID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))
FROM PRODUCT P
```

This query produces following output for me:

- M.Prod======>Ref Numb
- 1===========>NULL
- 2===========>NULL
- 3===========>981024605
- 3===========>981024669
- 4===========>981024688
- 4===========>981024723
- 5===========>NULL
- 6===========>NULL

The output I need in these cases is:

- M.Prod======>Ref Numb
- 1===========>981024583
- 2===========>981024719
- 3===========>981024605, 981024669
- 4===========>981024688, 981024723
- 5===========>981024742
- 6===========>981024742

Any solution for this will be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PRODUCT, 
    (STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + P1.REFNUMB AS [text()]
            FROM PRODUCT P1
            WHERE P1.PRODUCT = P.PRODUCT 
            AND (P1.SUBID = P.SUBID OR P1.SUBID IS NULL AND P.SUBID IS NULL)
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))
FROM PRODUCT P
```